# C++ Array on the heap

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory

If I declare an array on the heap, how can I get information about the array?

Here is my code:

```
class Wheel
{
public:
    Wheel() : pressure(32)
    {
        ptrSize = new int(30);
    }
    Wheel(int s, int p) : pressure(p)
    {
        ptrSize = new int(s);
    }
    ~Wheel()
    {
        delete ptrSize;
    }
    void pump(int amount)
    {
        pressure += amount;
    }
    int getSize()
    {
        return *ptrSize;
    }
    int getPressure()
    {
        return pressure;
    }
private:
    int *ptrSize;
    int pressure;
};
```

If I have the following:

```
Wheel *carWheels[4];
*carWheels = new Wheel[4];
cout << carWheels[0].getPressure();
```

How can I get call the .getPressure() method on any instance in the array when it is on the heap?
Also, if I want to create an array of Wheel on the heap, yet use this constructor when creating the array on the heap:

```
Wheel(int s, int p)
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Don't use raw arrays, they are not first class citizens in C++. Use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead. You will save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: Note that you need to follow the **[Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)** for your `Wheel` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Wheel *carWheels[4];
```

is an array of pointers to Wheel, so you need to initialize it with new:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < sizeof(carWheels)/sizeof(carWheels[0]); ++i)
  carWheels[i]=new Wheel(); // or any other c-tor like Wheel(int s, int p)
```

later you can access it like that:

```
carWheels[0]->getPressure();
```

size of array can be retrieved like above:

```
sizeof(carWheels)/sizeof(carWheels[0])
```

[edit - some more details]

If you want to stick to array you will need to pass its size on function call because arrays decays to pointers then. You might want to stay with following syntax:

```
void func (Wheel* (arr&)[4]){}
```

which I hope is correct, because I never use it, but better switch to std::vector.

Also with bare pointers in arrays you must remember to delete them at some point, also arrays does not protect you against exceptions - if any will happen you will stay with memory leaks.

Comment: When passed to a functio, `carWheels` loses size info, so your last expression won't work. And if it's no passed, there's no point to it, since you already know the size.

Comment: Why is the '->' used instead of a '.'?

Comment: @Darryl because `carWheels[0]` is a pointer to `Wheel`. Its the same as if you have `Wheel *myWheel = new Wheel();`, then you can say `myWheel->getPressuire();` or `(*myWheel).getPressure();`. The `->` just improves readability.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, replace

```
Wheel *carWheels[4];
```

with

```
std::vector<Wheel*> carWheels(4);
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++ )
   carWheels[i] = new Wheel(4);
```

You seem to be confusing `()` and `[]`, I suggest you look into that.

You do know that `ptrSize = new int(30);` doesn't create an array, right?

Answer (score 0):

Like C, you will need to lug the array's element count around with your allocation.

This information is actually stored by the implementation in some cases, but not in a way which is accessible to you.

In C++, we favor types such as std::vector and std::array.

---

Other notes:

```
ptrSize = new int(30); << creates one int with a value of 30
```

> How do I do this?
>        Wheel(int s, int p)

Typically, you would just use assignment if you have an existing element:

```
wheelsArray[0] = Wheel(1, 2);
```

because you will face difficulty creating an array with a non-default constructor.

and while we're at it:

```
std::vector<Wheel> wheels(4, Wheel(1, 2));
```

is all that is needed to create 4 Wheels if you use vector -- no `new` required. no `delete` required. plus, vector knows its size.